# Retrieve specific child values when know other child value in firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: This is my fire-base database]

I want to retrieve all the doctors'  "Firstname" and "Lastname" when I know the  "Speciality" of doctor.That's mean when I select specific Specialty area of doctor I want to get all the doctors names which have that  Specialty.

Comment: Where is your firebase database? The link is missing.

Comment: update question./

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to do that try the following:

```
DatabaseReference dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User").child("doctor");


dbRef.orderByChild("Spciality").equalTo("Pathologist").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() { 
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           for(DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                String firstName=datas.child("Firstname").getValue().toString();
                String lastName=datas.child("Lastname").getValue().toString();
              }
            }
        @Override
      public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

           }
       });
```

the snapshot is at child `doctor` then to retrieve based on the speciality value you need to use the query `orderByChild("Spciality").equalTo("Pathologist")` to be able to do that. You can change `Pathologist` as per your requirement.